# Removing all characters before certain string

Tags: php, string

How can I remove everything before the first ABC in a string?

So that this:
**somethingrandomABCotherrandomstuffABCmorerandomstuffABC**

turns to this:
**otherrandomstuffABCmorerandomstuffABC**.

Is this possible with php?

Comment: is this a generic case or..? also, what is the logic behind this? any rule to follow?

Comment: Explode the string, remove the first occurrence, glue it back together.

Comment: You can replace (by nothing in your case) a lot of things using [regular expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

Comment: Describe exactly what you are trying to achieve. I would bet you are creating a complex solution to a very simple problem. Why have you got these wierd string, do you create them yourself?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a php built in for doing this: [strstr](https://www.php.net/strstr)

Combine with substr to strip out your token:

```
$out = substr(strstr($text, 'ABC'), strlen('ABC'))
```

Comment: OP wants to skip "ABC", `strstr` includes `$needle` in result.

Comment: @KubaWyrostek you're right, thanks.  It is a somewhat common use case to use strstr with substr to strip out your token.  I added an example for clarification.

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php

function removeEverythingBefore($in, $before) {
    $pos = strpos($in, $before);
    return $pos !== FALSE
        ? substr($in, $pos + strlen($before), strlen($in))
        : "";
}

echo(removeEverythingBefore("somethingrandomABCotherrandomstuffABCmorerandomstuffABC", "ABC"));

?>
```

Outputs:

```
otherrandomstuffABCmorerandomstuffABC
```